# How to use xdebug with eclipse IDE for PHP?

Tags: php, php5, debugging, eclipse, xdebug

Hi my PHP project is set up on a remote test machine. I need to debug it using eclipse IDE. How shall I progress. I came to know i should prefer Xdebug rather than zend debugger.

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great guide: http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930

When you get to this bit:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Just change localhost to your external IP address